# Dual nationals under new US legislation, is my visa still valid?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, dual-nationality, iraqi-citizens

I am a dual national of Iraq and UK, my ESTA was denied in 2010 for unknown reason. No explanation was given, therefore I had to go for visa in US embassy and I was granted 10 years valid visa with multiple entry. I have been to US few times since then.

My question is under new restrictions for dual nationals, is this visa still valid or do I need a new visa as the situation is quite confusing ?

Comment: Perhaps you should write to the US consulate and ask.  They ought to respond in writing that your visa is still valid.  Then you can carry that letter with you in case you run into any trouble from someone who misunderstands the difference between revoking ESTA and revoking a visa.

Answer (score 10):

It's difficult to prove a negative but I haven't heard of any change to the visa regulations. In fact, the changes to the visa waiver program are explicitly intended to force people in your situation to apply for a visa, which you already did, so I would assume that yours is still valid. [Per the official website](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html):

> These individuals will still be able to apply for a visa using the regular appointment process at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate.